# React boilerplate : Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-boilerplate

I'm trying to create [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) but got bellow error.

```
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dev1/.npm/_logs/2019-02-05T10_12_55_340Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-boilerplate@3.7.0 presetup: `npm i chalk shelljs`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-boilerplate@3.7.0 presetup script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dev1/.npm/_logs/2019-02-05T10_12_55_434Z-debug.log
```

Node version : v8.9.4

I've clone setup from git and run `npm run setup` command but got this error.

**Note:
`remove node_modues and re-install node_modules` - not working
`uninstall node globaly and re-install node` - not working**

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the npm logs and I saw that it was failing at install @xtuc/ieee754
I found this solution https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12231

Its likely that you have to remove your ~/.npmrc file.

I tried this and it solved the issue for me.

Hope this helps!

**This issue just wasted my 6 hours only :(**

Answer (score 2):

I spent few hours resolving this issue. Below solution worked for me

```
rm -rf node_modules

npm cache clean --f

npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you need to manually/explicitly assign the call stack so that the call stack size is increased to perform that operation. You can try:

```
node --stack-size=16000 <file>
```

Since you are doing `npm run setup` so you need to basically change that call stack value in `setup` script in `package.json`, something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "setup": "node --stack-size=16000 index.js"
}
```

If that still gives the stack size error then try with greater value other than `16000`

Comment: Thanks @Ankit Agrawal, Now I'm getting `Not Found: @xtuc/ieee754@https://registry.npmjs.org/@xtuc/ieee754/-/ieee754-1.2.0.tgz` 
I've search for this error, but not working any solution....
Can you help more?

Comment: Try doing `npm rebuild`

Comment: after 'rebuild ' I got same error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. :(

Comment: if I run `npm run setup` got `Not Found: @xtuc/ieee754@https://registry...` error and If I run `npm start` got `Maximum call stack...` error..